# USB 3.0(super speed) frame and packet sizes

Tags: usb, zynq

I am working with hardware which support USB3.0 interface. According to USB standard spec it support 5Gbps data rates.
Now I want to know what is best way of effective utilization of USB bandwidth.

> > What's the recommended maximum packet size and frame sizes?

In my scenario I need to send huge amount of data (60GB) as fast as possible. How do form these data into packets.

As per USB spec we can send 1frame/mille second, so to get 5Gbps data rate what is the number of packets/frame required?

Give some brief explanation on USB3.0 protocol.

Thank you.

Comment: 1 frame/millisecond is for Full speed device.
1 frame/microsecond is for High speed device
Super speed protocol has removed the the framing concept. Instead of SOF, USB 3.0 host sends ITP packets for time synchronization.

Comment: Can you please give some more details. How could I send 1frame/microsecond, because as per USB standard spec it generates SOF(start of frame) for every 1ms. Even though 1frame/microsecond is possible, What is maximum number of packets can send per 1 frame, also what is the maximum packet sizes in terms of bytes.

Comment: Again SOF is a concept for USB 2.0 and not USB 3.0.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how many packet are allowed to send per frame & maximum packet size. Because I need to send huge amount of data in the range of 60GB in my application.

Comment: 1frame/microsecond Oh..! If I send min 1 packet of 1024Bytes in one frame, its approximately 8Gbps, but super speed spec if 5Gbps. How it could be possible .